# Feature selection in clustering

Tags: clustering, data-mining, feature-selection, k-means, model-based-clustering

I am looking for a method for feature selection in Gaussian Mixture Models. I have a dataset with 2000 records and 40 variables. I tried to use the "clustvarsel" package in R, which use the BIC as index to compare the different models, but I could not make it work. I get always an error. Do you know any other approach and R packages I could use? 
I am also using sparse kmeans. Applying this method I get a vector with weights for each parameter. Can I use that as an indication of the relative importance of the variables for the classification?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the R package VarSelLCM [https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VarSelLCM/index.html][VarSelLCM]